# compactness of a set of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

I'm sorry if this is probably a stupid and not well-posed question but I'm really new to topology.
I have two compact sets $U\subset \mathbb R ^n$ and $Y\subset \mathbb R$. Then I define $Q$ to be the set of all the possible sequences $((u_k,y_k))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ where, for any $k\in\mathbb N$, $u_k\in U$ and $y_k\in Y$.
Since $U$ and $Y$ are compact then their elements are bounded  and hence $Q\subset l_\infty$ (is this right?).
So I have two compact sets, I take sequences of samples from them and I fill $Q$, then I would like to know if $Q$ is compact, but I'm really missing the point. To prove sequential compactness I would have to show that any sequence $(q_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ where $q_k\in Q$ has an infinite subsequence converging to some point in $Q$, right? how can I proceed?

Comment: You need a topology on $Q$ to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $Q$ is in bijection with $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} U \times Y$ (do you see why?). So there is a natural topology on $Q$, namely the product topology.

Now Tychonoff's theorem tells you that $Q$ is compact.

Comment: (informally) do you mean that taking an infinite sequence of elements in $U\times Y$ is actually taking a "vector" living in $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N} U\times Y$? and thus I just have to consider the product topology on this latter space?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. You could imagine putting other topologies on $Q$, but this one seems pretty natural and is easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the topology that you choose for $Q$.

Let $K=U \times Y$. This is compact in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$.

Then $Q = \{ x | \mathbb{N} \to K \}$.

If you choose the discrete topology, then $Q$ is not compact.

If you choose the topology of pointwise convergence (the product topology)
then $Q$ is compact.